# Is the phrase "albeit the fact that..." correct?

Tags: word-usage

I recently came across the phrase *albeit the fact* in a book I was reading, and, as a professional editor, I was immediately struck by how ungrammatical it sounded to me. So I searched Google Books and found a shocking number of published works containing this phrase — mostly government and scientific reports — which led me to think that it's primarily being used by people who want/need to sound intelligent, but don't really know how to use *albeit*. I searched all the trusted dictionaries and couldn't find one instance of this phrase, and the more I replay it, the worse it sounds. Am I missing something?

[Here](https://www.ellsworthamerican.com/opinions/un-american-and-out-of-line/)'s an example from The Ellsworth American:

> On the matter of Mr. Thomas’s scathing remarks concerning the managing
> editor of The Ellsworth American, first of all, let it be said that
> the reputation of the American speaks for itself. Beyond its having
> been acclaimed several times over as the best weekly publication in
> Maine, it ranks the best source for balanced political reporting of
> any publication in the state, **albeit the fact that** its readership and
> contributors to letters to the editor and opinion pieces are generally
> of a liberal-progressive mindset. So be it, but it’s nice to see the
> conservative point of view come through once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a misuse of "albeit". A typical use is:

> He was making progress, albeit rather slowly.

This essentially means the same thing as

> He was making progress rather slowly.

but emphasizes that the slowness is unexpected.

In your quoted phrase, they seem to be using "albeit" as a synonym for "despite". And they could dispense with clumsy "the fact that" phrase entirely if they used "even though".

Answer (score -1):

It's not strictly speaking *incorrect*. However, I tend to agree with your belief that it's "primarily being used by people who want/need to sound intelligent" as there are more efficient and less clumsy ways of stating the same idea; i.e., replace "albeit the fact that" with "although".